# Best way for rock solid system snapshots on fedora

Tags: fedora, backup, btrfs

What is a simple way to backup my system packages daily so I can rollback to the exact same state should I mess up (System files only not /home)

Ideally I would be able to restore from the Fedora recovery rescue environment something I don't think I can do with BTRFS snapshots.

Although I would love to be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways is to use a filesystem that supports snapshots (like zfs).  There are packages that do in place backups using scheduled zfs snapshots that get taken and expired.

You would control which files get rolled back by separating them into separate zfs volumes.  So you would have a system volume, a /var volume, a /home volume, etc., and manage snapshots for them all separately.

ZFS also supports directly reading files in old snapshots without rolling back, so you can do a manual partial roll back of a single file if you want to.